# Use python subprocess module like a command line simulator

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a test framework in Python for a command line application. The application will create directories, call other shell scripts in the current directory and will output on the Stdout.

I am trying to treat {Python-SubProcess, CommandLine} combo as equivalent to {Selenium, Browser}. The first component *plays* something on the second and *checks* if the output is expected. I am facing the following problems

1. The Popen construct takes a command and returns back after that command is completed. What I want is a live handle to the process so I can run further commands + verifications and finally close the shell once done
2. I am okay with writing some infrastructure code for achieveing this since we have a lot of  command line applications that need testing like this.

Here is a sample code that I am running

```
 p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", cwd = test_dir)
 p.communicate(input = "hostname") --> I expect the hostname to be printed out
 p.communicate(input = "time") --> I expect current time to be printed out
```

but the process hangs or may be I am doing something wrong. Also how do I "grab" the output of that sub process so I can *assert* that something exists?

Comment: You can not call communicate() twice for a single process. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Is communicate('hostname\ntime\nexit\n') possible? Do you really need to work with the process interactively, or just execute multiple commands? The latter is way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` allows you to continue execution after starting a process. The `Popen` objects expose `wait()`, `poll()` and many other methods to communicate with a child process when it is running. Isn't it what you need?

See [Popen constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and `Popen` objects description for details.

Here is a small example that runs Bash on Unix systems and executes a command:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen (['/bin/sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
sout, serr = p.communicate('ls\n')
print 'OUT:'
print sout
print 'ERR:'
print serr
```

**UPD:** `communicate()` waits for process termination. If you do not need that, you may use the appropriate pipes directly, though that usually gives you rather ugly code.

**UPD2:** You updated the question. Yes, you cannot call `communicate` twice for a single process. You may either give all commands you need to execute in a single call to `communicate` and check the whole output, or work with pipes (`Popen.stdin`, `Popen.stdout`, `Popen.stderr`). If possible, I strongly recommend the first solution (using `communicate`).

Otherwise you will have to put a command to input and wait for some time for desired output. What you need is non-blocking read to avoid hanging when there is nothing to read. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) is a recipe how to emulate a non-blocking mode on pipes using threads. The code is ugly and strangely complicated for such a trivial purpose, but that's how it's done.

Another option could be using `p.stdout.fileno()` for `select.select()` call, but that won't work on Windows (on Windows `select` operates only on objects originating from WinSock). You may consider it if you are not on Windows.

Comment: I see I was missing the stdin=PIPE. Let me give it a try

Comment: Yes, stdin=PIPE is essential. Think that was the problem.

Comment: So how do I run two calls of communicate as above? The above program hangs? (The one I have in my example)

Comment: Right I get it now. I can create some infrastructure that creates a list of commands and call Process n times and some asserting infrastructure too.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using plain `subprocess` you might find Python sh library very useful:

http://amoffat.github.com/sh/

Here is an example how to build in an asynchronous interaction loop with sh:

http://amoffat.github.com/sh/tutorials/2-interacting_with_processes.html

Another (old) library for solving this problem is pexpect:

http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: As far as I understand, sh and pexpect are POSIX-only libraries.

Comment: I meant Unix-like systems. Windows is really a problem here. Everything seems to work, but there is a lot of nasty details, like select() not working with pipes. A week ago I faced nearly the same task in a project that should work both on Linux and Windows, and all my solutions for Windows were ugly.

Comment: Ah, sorry @Ellioh. I was just joking... usually no one wants to do command-line manipulation in Windows, because Windows has its own APIs to deal with things (think Microsoft PowerShell).

Comment: great library, exactly what I was waiting for.